# Windows Phone 8 touch positions in Direct3D

Tags: c++, touch, directx, direct3d, windows-phone-8

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to handle touches in a purely native C++ Direct3D application in Windows Phone 8. Has anybody managed to get touch input in to their game? Everything I read online is either related to XAML/Silverlight or desktop metro apps. i have been told by many people at Microsoft that this feature is supported so i know that it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at some level your C++ Direct3D app on Windows Phone 8 (or Windows 8) will be using CoreWindow.

CoreWindow has pointer events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.pointerpressed.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Which are available from C++ as well.